# NextJS screen flicker on authentication check using localstorage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am authenticating my NextJS frontend from a backend that gives me an `accessToken` on a successful email / password login (Laravel Sanctum). From there I am saving that accessToken in local storage.

If i have a page that needs protecting, for instance `/profile`, i need to verify that the token is valid before showing the page. If it is not valid, they need to be redirected to the `/signin` page. So i have the following code which does that.

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import { useEffect } from 'react';

export default function Profile() {
    const router = useRouter();

    useEffect(async () => {
        const token = localStorage.getItem('accessToken');

        const resp = await fetch('https://theapiuri/api/user', {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
            }
        });

        const json = await resp.json();

        if (!token && json.status !== 200) {
            router.push('/signin');
        }
    })

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Protected Profile Page</h1>
        </div>
    )
}
```

It works, sort of. If I am logged out, and i try to visit `/profile` it will flash up the profile page for a second or so and then redirect to signin.

This doesn't look good at all. I was wondering if anyone in the same situation could share their solution, or if anyone has some advice that would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your basic problem is that you are returning the profile page immediately, but the token authentication is async. You should wait for the authentication to happen before showing the page. There's different ways to do that, but a basic way is to just set a variable in your state and then change what is returned by the render function based on that variable.

As an example, here I suppose that you have some component that just shows a loader or spinner or something like that:

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import LoaderComponent from 'components/Loader';

export default function Profile() {
    const router = useRouter();
    const [hasAccess, setHasAccess] = useState(false);

    useEffect(async () => {
        const token = localStorage.getItem('accessToken');

        const resp = await fetch('https://theapiuri/api/user', {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
            }
        });

        const json = await resp.json();

        if (!token && json.status !== 200) {
            router.push('/signin');
        } else {
            setHasAccess(true);
        }
    })

    if (!hasAccess) {
        return (
           <LoaderComponent />
        );
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Protected Profile Page</h1>
        </div>
    )
}
```